# How to enable TLS/SSL in OOzie email action

Tags: oozie, email

I have to tried to configure gmail account in oozie email action.
But unfortunatly it throws below error,

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
```

While digging into the smtp properties in oozie only below properties can be configured,

From,SMTP host,Port,User name and password if authentication is enabled.
But no way to enable the SSL/TLS.
How do i enable this in our oozie email action?.

Comment: Which Oozie version are you using?

Comment: Server version 4.1.0-cdh5.5.1

Comment: Can you connect to the node that runs Oozie service, and send a mail from there *(e.g. via `mailx`)*? If yes, then can you tell Oozie to send the mail to the **local** SMTP service and let that service *(probably `postfix`)* manage the forwarding with TLS?

Comment: No i am not able to send mail from node where oozie server runs. The node is configured to accept only gmail smtp at specific port. Is this the only way the TLS can be enabled?